# Front-end form with Craft CMS for users to submit entries not working?

Tags: forms, twig, craftcms

I've put together an entry form to allow registered users to submit content. I followed the example given in the Craft 3 Docs but it still doesn't seem to work. Was hoping someone could see what I can't. Here is the code I'm using for my form.

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
{% if errors %}
    <ul class="errors">
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import errorList %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">
    {{ redirectInput('viewentry/{slug}') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="work" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title"
    {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.title }}"{% endif -%}>

    {% if entry is defined %}
        {{ errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}
    {% endif %}

    <label for="fields-projectDescription">Project Description</label>
    <textarea id="fields-projectDescription" name="fields[projectDescription]">
    {%- if entry is defined %}{{ entry.projectDescription }}{% endif -%}
    </textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Publish">
</form>
```

The error I recieve when this form is submitted is:

> Bad Request Request - missing required body param

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WgK9.png)

I though this could mean I was required to keep the 'body' field form the example. eg.

```
<label for="body">Body</label>
<textarea id="body" name="fields[body]">
    {%- if entry is defined %}{{ entry.body }}{% endif -%}
</textarea>

{% if entry is defined %}
    {{ errorList(entry.getErrors('body')) }}
{% endif %}
```

However, adding this in made no difference.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `sectionId` in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="{{ craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('sectionHandle').id }}">
```

Comment: Better to use  `{{ hiddenInput('sectionId', craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('sectionHandle').id) }}`